# Selenium-PHPUnit Error accessing elements in an IFrame

Tags: iframe, selenium, phpunit

I need some advice on the implementations of selenium-phpunit.
I am using selenium RC and phpunit with php-webdriver-bindings that connects phpunit and selenium to perform some automated testing tasks.

The problem is coming when I am trying to access elements present in an iframe. A normal getElementBy(LocatorStrategy::id,'@requiredelement') is not working as it gives a "NoSuchElementException" when running the code using "phpunit filename.php" .

There are some implementations for changing windows in the middle of implementation for an iframe in java, c#, python from what I've seen in some of the Q&As. Not sure if those implementations present for php.

I am running on Ubuntu 12.04 with phpunit 3.7 and include_file "webdriver.php" and it's related functions' of the php-webdriver-bindings (http://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/). Elements in a iframe are not getting detected.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use that:

```
$this->selectFrame("<xpath to get iframe>>"); // for example: //*[@id='iframe']
$this->assertElementPresent("<xpath to get to element in frame>");
```

have chacked just a minute ago - it works =)

Comment: sorry for replying so late. It was actually working. Thanks for the advice. That value of $this should be changed from the loaded page to the frame essentially making iframe as the parent.